# Create and switch between Edit / View Templates for a control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, visualstatemanager

I have a TextBlock that dislays a message.  I have to build the ability to edit and save this message.  When the Edit Icon is clicked, instead of popping up another view with a TextBox and a Save Button, I wanted to somehow just show a Textbox and Save Button in place of the TextBlock.  Then when Save is clicked it would change the State back again only showing the read only TextBlock.

I thought that I could do this with the VisualStateManager but it seems you can only do Storyboards for States and even if I leave the button always there and make it invisible I can't seem to change the Property Value between States either.

Is VisualStateManager the answer for this or is there something better to use?

**Update**
I found and followed this example [View / Edit Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042869/wpf-a-good-way-to-make-a-view-edit-control) and it looks like it will solve my issue.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.Test2"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Name="MyTest"  c:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.Enabled="True" c:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.DoLock="False" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Message}"  >

        <Control.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <TextBox Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="100,0" />

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Control.Template>
        <c:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.LockTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="3">
                    <TextBlock Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" Foreground="White" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </c:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.LockTemplate>
    </Label>
    <WrapPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="ReadOnly"   Width="70" Height="25" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
        <Button Content="Edit"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="50" Height="25" Click="Button_Click2" />
    </WrapPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could be to do with the `UpdateSourceTrigger` - might be that when you type into the textbox and then click `Save` it's not actually losing focus properly and validating the content. Did you breakpoint the binding to your textbox to see if it fires a property changed event (another call to the getter of the bound property)?

Comment: I hadn't bound it to anything yet.  For this test I was just rendering editable then clicking the button which changes the Control Template from a TextBox to a TextBlock with a border.  So when I type "This is a Test" in the TextBox and click Change I see the TextBlock with the border, just no Text.

Comment: Your comment got me to thinking and I got it now.  I had to use regular binding like this:  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text }"  Normally I thought you use TemplateBinding in Control Templates but it seems to be different in this case.

Comment: You usually do - if you want to bind to the underlying controls properties, anyway good that you sorted it :)